# Is there a cost to using google realtime api? What is the user limit? What is the cost to add users?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

What is the cost to use google realtime api for a company?
Is there a cost if the number of users go  up?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Realtime API is free. However what you need to be aware of is its [Size restrictions and best practices](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/size).

> The Realtime API limits the maximum sizes of Realtime documents and
>   individual changes. These limits are:
>
> Total Realtime document size: 10 MB (10*2^10 bytes) Maximum change
>   size: 500 KB
>
> -Avoid storing large binary objects, like images, within the data model. Instead, you can link to files stored separately in Google
>   Drive, or on an external server.